# Using intent-filter to open file type with Adobe AIR app

Tags: android, actionscript-3, air, android-manifest

I'm trying to set my **Adobe AIR** Android app to automatically be used to open a specific type of file. I've gone through many examples of this but haven't been able to find one that works correctly (many relevant questions on SO are 4-6 years old and perhaps no longer accurate?).

Let's say I want to open a binary file with extension .abc in my app. This is what I've added to my application descriptor:

```
<android>
    <manifestAdditions>
    <![CDATA[
        <manifest android:installLocation="auto">
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-feature android:required="true" android:name="android.hardware.touchscreen.multitouch" />
    <application>
        <activity android:name="com.example.myapp.OpenFileActivity" android:label="MyApp">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"/>
                <data android:mimeType="application/abc"/>
            </intent-filter>

            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"/>
                <data android:mimeType="application/octet-stream"/>
            </intent-filter>
            
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
                <data android:scheme="content" />
                <data android:mimeType="*/*" />
                <data android:pathPattern=".*\\.abc" />
                <data android:host="*" />
            </intent-filter>
            
        </activity>
    </application>
        </manifest>
    ]]>
    </manifestAdditions>
</android>
```

AS3 code (just trying to get the Invoke working before I try to add any functionality to it):

```
//...
NativeApplication.nativeApplication.addEventListener(InvokeEvent.INVOKE, onInvoke);
//...    
    
private function onInvoke(e:InvokeEvent):void {
    trace(e.toString());
}
```

After I install the app using the above code in the application descriptor, if I try to open an ABC file (for example, by tapping an attachment in Gmail) a message immediately appears "Unfortunately, [app name] has stopped."

If I look through logcat, I see the error:

> E/AndroidRuntime(13835): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.example.myapp/com.example.myapp.OpenFileActivity}:
>
> java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.example.myapp.OpenFileActivity" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.example.myapp-1.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app-lib/com.example.myapp-1, /vendor/lib, /system/lib]]

but if I remove the `android:name="com.example.myapp.OpenFileActivity"`, I get a build error: `Tag <activity> missing required attribute name.`

What am I missing or doing wrong? **Please keep in mind this is an Adobe AIR app and not a native Android app.**

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the activity you are defining `OpenFileActivity` isn't actually a java Activity class instance in your application hence the class not found error.

We use the following for controlling the main AIR activity:

```
<manifestAdditions>
    <![CDATA[
    <manifest android:installLocation="auto">

        <application>
            <activity>
                <intent-filter>
                    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
                    <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
                </intent-filter>
                <intent-filter>
                    <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"/>
                    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
                    <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"/>
                    <data android:scheme="custom_url_scheme" />
                </intent-filter>
            </activity>

        </application>

    </manifest>
    ]]>
</manifestAdditions>
```

Using the blank activity node should add the intent filters to the actual AIR application activity. So you should be able to add the other intent filters you require at that point.